# Add shell or bash to a docker image (Distroless based on Debian GNU/Linux)

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, glibc, docker-entrypoint

I want add `shell` or `bash` to my image to execute installation command.

I have copied the `/bin/bash` on my VM on to my image on `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY /bin/bash /bin/
```

But when I execute the docker command:

```
 docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" <my_image>
```

Then I get the following error :

> `/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you expand this question to include a [mcve], especially including the `FROM` line of the Dockerfile?  (Is it "distroless", or "based on the Debian distribution"?)  How would you ordinarily install software into this image?  (Does it include some sort of package manager?)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, On my Dokerfile, I go from  api-gate-way image based on distroless with nginx configuration

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it by copying the statically compiled shell from official [`busybox` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox) in a multi-stage build in your Dockerfile. Or just `COPY --from` it.

The static shell doesn't have too many dependencies, so it will work for a range of different base images. It may not work for some advanced cases, but otherwise it gets the job done.

The statically compiled shell is tagged with `uclibc`. Depending on your base image you may have success with other flavours of `busybox` as well.

Example:

```
FROM busybox:1.35.0-uclibc as busybox

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

# Now copy the static shell into base image.
COPY --from=busybox /bin/sh /bin/sh

# You may also copy all necessary executables into distroless image.
COPY --from=busybox /bin/mkdir /bin/mkdir
COPY --from=busybox /bin/cat /bin/cat

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The single-line `COPY --from` directly from image would also work:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

COPY --from=busybox:1.35.0-uclibc /bin/sh /bin/sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Brilliant! And you'll also likely win a new Lurker badge for the first time answer being a hit after minimum of 9 years of using SO in stealth mode:)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks :D The Lurker badge definitely should exist!

Comment: Does not seem to work for me:
`starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown`

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk What base and busybox image do you use?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Busybox: busybox:1.35.0-uclibc & base: gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot

Answer (score 10):

[Google's distroless images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) have versions tagged `debug`, which contain `busybox` executable (with `sh` bundled in).

If you have to, you can arguably use them even in production (which defeats the purpose of increased security - such as hiding environment variables and protecting scripted apps code).

Usage example of the `distroless/base` image with `debug` tag:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name base -u 0 gcr.io/distroless/base:debug
/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
```

Comment: Actually nowadays base:debug does not contain bash...

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek I believe it has never contained `bash` per se (`/usr/bin/bash`), just the shells bundled with `busybox`, i.e. `/busybox/sh -> busybox` and `/busybox/ash -> busybox`

Answer (score 8):

That's because you're trying to use dynamic-compiled `bash` in in `docker` without `glibc` support.

### TL;DR

- ... either use [`bash-static`](https://github.com/robxu9/bash-static) instead of classic `bash`
  You may [download](https://github.com/robxu9/bash-static/releases) it or run [`./build.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robxu9/bash-static/master/build.sh)
- or add `bash` for `alpine`: add this line to your `Dockerfile`: `RUN apk add --no-cache bash`

### `Alpine` is a `musl`-based distro

Many docker images are built with `alpine` as base image:
`alpine` (usually) is small & fast:

Here are the sizes of the images of popular operating systems.

[image: The difference in image size]
source: [A Breakdown of Operating Systems of Dockerhub](https://anchore.com/blog/breakdown-of-operating-systems-of-dockerhub/)

> The difference in image size is striking: the range goes from BusyBox at 1MB all the way up to Fedora at 230MB. It’s interesting to see the clustering happening. Alpine and BusyBox are lightweight and right near 0MB, then the midweights like Debian and Ubuntu are around 100MB, and largest are heavyweights such as CentOS and Oracle Linux up by 200MB.

## `musl` doesn't contain `libtinfo`

See more about difference between `glibc` and `musl` [Functional differences from glibc](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Dynamic-linker)

### P.S. you can run `bash-static` even in empty container from `scratch`

```
FROM scratch
ADD bash
ENTRYPOINT ['/bash']
```

You could probably add busybox in now.

Comment: Thank you for your message @Yasen. I will try with this 'RUN apk add --no-cache bash'

Comment: I have added the command on my Dockerfile :'RUN apk add --no-cache bash' but I have this error: Step 4/5 : RUN apk add --no-cache bash
 ---> Running in 99bf0a92c050
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: How do you execute the "apk" command if you can't use a shell? The distroless docker images hasn't shell.